# Warning message on "SettingWithCopyWarning"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying an exercise from a DataQuest proyect, and when creating a 'month' column from a datetime variable, to aggregate values, I get a warning message that I don't know how to use to fix my code (I've read something about this warning message, but didn't find the connection with my code).

My piece of code:

```
#Create a new column containing the month
daytime_data['month'] = daytime_data['date_time'].dt.month

#Aggregate the data and avearge it by month
by_month = daytime_data.groupby('month').mean()
print(by_month['traffic_volume'])
```

The warning message:

*C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4856/2147418321.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
daytime_data['month'] = daytime_data['date_time'].dt.month*

Could you please help me find what should I fix in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your warning message. to remove this error simply change the

```
daytime_data['month'] = daytime_data['date_time'].dt.month
```

into

```
daytime_data.loc[:, 'month'] = daytime_data['date_time'].dt.month
```

Comment: Hi Waleed!

I already tried that, but it doesn't work, either :( - this is the warning message that I get when I try that code:

*C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1667: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = value*

Comment: Can you post the link to the DataQuest excersice and your complete code so I may try to replicate the issue?

Comment: Sure! Here's the link to the full exercise and code: https://community.dataquest.io/t/my-answer-to-guided-project-finding-heavy-traffic-indicators-on-i-94/561401

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response Alvaro. After looking at your code I have identified the issue. The issue is that daytime_data itself is a slice of the metro dataframe. To remove this error, create the daytime_data dataframe from a copy of the metro dataframe by simply adding the copy() method to it. ```daytime_data = metro.copy(deep=True)[(metro['date_time'].dt.hour >= 7) & (metro['date_time'].dt.hour < 19)]```

Comment: This can also be split into two lines if you prefer.

```daytime_data = metro.copy(deep=True)```
```daytime_data['month'] = daytime_data['date_time'].dt.month```